# Ansible ssh_args affecting sftp and scp connections

Tags: ansible

I want to use Ansible to update some remove Ubuntu Servers with no internet access, I've downloaded a created a repo on the Ansible hosted by nginx http://localhost/media/apt

In order to the remote servers to get the repo, I've overwritten the sources.list to be:

```
deb http://127.0.0.1:88/media/apt trusty main
```

I've put in the ansible.cfg file:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -R 88:127.0.0.1:80
```

For completeness here is my yml file:

```
- name: apt proxy configuration
  copy:
    src: sources.list
    dest: /etc/apt/sources.list

- name: APT | ge repo key
  apt_key:
    data: "{{repository_key }}"

- name: Upgrade
  apt:
    update_cache: yes
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
    upgrade: dist
```

The script does the job it updates the sources file, installs the key and updates the remote system, which is fantastic.

However by interfering with the ssh_args, I've upset ansible with every task I now get two warnings:
*

> [WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.128.129]. Use
>   ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
>
> [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.128.129]. Use
>   ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

I can see it's adding my ssh_args options into the sftp and scp transfers

> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -R 88:127.0.0.1:80 -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 '[192.168.128.129]'
>
> <192.168.128.129> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -R 88:127.0.0.1:80 -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 '[192.168.128.129]'  [WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.128.129]. Use
>   ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
>
> <192.168.128.129> SSH: EXEC scp -R 88:127.0.0.1:80 -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 /tmp/tmp87UMuT '[192.168.128.129]:/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1509468784.12-45526153395602/setup.py'
>   [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [192.168.128.129]. Use
>   ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

Is there a way I can connect to my remote machine with a reverse proxy in place without upsetting ansible scp and ftp connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read through [the documentation on the ssh connection module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/connection/ssh.html), you will see that in addition to `ssh_args`, which as you have discovered is used for all ssh-related command lines, there are also a number of `*_extra_args` options:

- `ssh_extra_args`
- `scp_extra_args`
- `sftp_extra_args`

These arguments will only be used for the specific command.  In other words, if you use `ssh_extra_args` you should be all set.

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to add this to my default/main.yml as
ansible_ssh_extra_args: -R 88:127.0.0.1:80 

Thanks again.

Comment: Updated Link to [ssh documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html)